# What recourse does FINRA provide?

Tags: united-states, stocks, brokerage, regulation

I am contemplating bringing a complaint against a brokerage regarding an order in good standing that was not processed correctly.

If FINRA does find against the broker, other than fines/sanctions, what are FINRA's powers? Are they able to force a trade backdated, force a backdate deposit... etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the complaint as well as how the other party decides to respond.  Here are my two experiences with this and  they are not a  representation of all that FINRA does in such situations.

1) In 1987, I had a $15 covered call position on Bear Stearns that expired two points in-the-money.  I should have been assigned.  The next trading day was the crash of 1987 and it took Paine Webber 8 days to figure out whether I had been assigned or not.  By then, BSC had dropped to about $13. I had been  unable to defend the position if indeed I still owned it.   I indicated that I was going take take them to arbitration and they chose to settle, crediting my account  with $200 per 100 shares.

2) During the Internet craze, I was dealing with a number of firms, one of which was a "Maggot Mile" broker (located in Boca Raton Florida) who had a string of IPOs that opened for trading on their first day at multiples of the IPO price.  I knew what I was dealing with.  I did 3 of them and for the last one, the broker refused to execute a trade to sell the balance of a profitable equity position (brokers lose allocation in future deals if their clients are flippers).  My loss was the gains since I had sold some shares already.  Shortly thereafter, the SEC closed the firm down due to illegal practices and poof, profits gone,

I filed a complaint against the broker and the firm.  I had no expectation of receiving remuneration since the firm was kaput.  I just wanted to put a "Yes" violation on the broker's license (I don't know the specific terms).  It was all handled by mail.  I provided a written statement and other documentation and then each party responded back and forth.  After about 8 months, I received a verdict in my favor, 50% against the broker and 50% against the brokerage firm.  In order to get a job at a new firm, the broker had to settle with me.  Found money.

FINRA has a process for arbitration:

https://www.finra.org/arbitration-and-mediation/arbitration-process

Don't bother with a complaint unless you can provide clear cut evidence of malfeasance.